# Is $f(E)$ a measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel (or just Lebesgue measurable) function. Let $E$ be a Borel set (or measurable set).
Is $f(E)$ is a measurable set?  Some additional conditions may be imposed to $f$, such as right continuity and monotonicity.

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/133195/69037).

Comment: @Arrow THX man.